# provider: Named Pipes Provider, error:40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, exception, connection, database-connection, sqlconnection

I have hosted an asp.net application in godaddy.
My database is present in discountasp.net, when im accessing my application it throws
following error.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
The server was not found or was not accessible.
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server).

Same application, I have hosted in Somee.com and connecting to same database in discount asp which is working fine.

I have tried adding tcp port number 1433 in connection string, then it throws time out error.
Remote connection is enabled and authentication mode is SQL Server and Windows Authentication.
Im trying to open SQL Server Configuration, it says you dont have permission.
My connection string is Data Source=***********.discountasp.net; Initial Catalog=dbname; User ID=username; Password=**************